# What to do when I get "Unable to Verify App" error on iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, code-signing-certificate

Here's the error that's popping up whenever I'm trying to open the app:

[image]

I do have Internet connections. I restarted the iPad multiple times and reconnected to the Internet multiple times too. If it helps, one of provisioning profiles was invalid earlier:

[image]

So I enabled it, which generated a `<something>.mobileprovision` file, what should I do with it?

-------------------------**UPDATE 1**-------------------------

I opened "Device Management" in Settings > General, here's what's inside:

[image]

[image]

Finally, when I go to "More Details" of this profile, I see:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go to your iPhone Settings > General > Device Management and then trust your associated certificate.
Hope this helps .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't see how I could trust any certificate. I've updated the question, please check in out.

Comment: Your provisioning profile or certificates are not expired ? Right? It is showing expired on 28 july

Comment: For me it worked with restarting the iPhone